# Search for online Skype users

Tags: search, skype

Is there a way to find only online Skype users? In the earlier versions, there were a "Skype Me" mode that disappeared. Are there any other utilities to find online people to chat?

Example: I came from Berlin to France and I searched for German-speaking online Skype users from Paris to help me finding interesting places.

Answer (score 1):

Skype-me mode still exists. I just tried your search (German speakers in France, but couldn't specify Paris).  The dialog a tick-box to search users in SkypeMe mode.  In Skype 2.8.0.851 for OS-X the tick-box is to the right of the language drop-down.

Comment: "still"? How did you find version 2.8? I use 4.2.0.169 for Windows... and there is no option like this

Comment: Ok, perhaps that information is out of date.  But Skype's auto-update just said I have the latest version.  The Windows version may have gone beyond us.  (Nah, that wouldn't happen.....)